# Selectively overwrite partitions in Delta Live Table pipeline

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I have relatively big table and it is overwritten in DLT pipeline. It is partitioned by date and in most cases I change small portion of data (connected to last couple of partitions). Is it possible to selectively overwrite only specified partitions?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://docs.databricks.com/delta/selective-overwrite.html

Comment: Yes it is, but I need confirmation if this works in DLT pipeline. I don't call `write` there and not sure how I would pass this option.